# CSS Overflow-x:scroll is showing content

Tags: php, css

I've searched through various forum posts on Overflow-x:scroll, which explain how to implement it, and in most cases the same fix has resolved the OP's issue.

However, I have followed these posts and still cannot seem to resolve my issue, please help!

I am creating an image preview pane (Large image, list of thumbnails), and I am trying to place the thumbnails in a scrollable DIV horizontally, but am striking out over and over again.

With my current code I have set the width to 200px, but despite the presence of overflow-x, the div is still showing all of the thumbnails across the screen.

```
#Thumbview { position:relative; height:100px; width:200px; overflow-x:scroll; overflow-y:hidden; white-space:nowrap; }
```

My PHP is as follows for this small bit:

```
<div id="ThumbView">
      <?php
       // Create a slide-able thumbnail view.
       $piclist = explode(", ", $datafiller['PictureList']);
       foreach ($piclist as $thumbnail) {
        echo "<img src=\"./Images/Inventory/" . $_GET['carid'] . "/thumbnails/" . $thumbnail . "\">";
       }
      ?>
     </div>
```

I have attempted to enclose each IMG in a DIV, with no luck, change display types on both the container and the children to various inline elements. Still no change. Ideas?

Comment: For sure you see content if `overflow-x: scroll` isset, because you get a scrollbar! If you want to cut the content use `overflow-x: hidden` Otherwise if i missunderstand something please post a image how it looks and whats wrong

Comment: Your CSS is for Thumbview with a small 'v'.  Your id is ThumbView with a capital 'V'.

Comment: Rizier123: I want a scrollbar to appear, it is not appearing, all of the DIV content is overflowing the confines of the DIV...

Comment: Chris Barlow: ...OMG. I have been fighting this half of the day. I... I don't know how I overlooked this so many times today. Matching case in the CSS and the PHP fixed it... Sorry for wasting everyone's time. And, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your id names should match (care about the V)

```
<div id="ThumbView">

#ThumbView
```

is this what u need?
http://jsfiddle.net/x96hq47c/

Comment: As per the comment offered by Chris Barlow, this fixed it. Took everyone spectacular on Stack to figure this critical item out for me. A simple mistake on my part. Sorry if I've wasted everyone's time! Thank you so much for taking the time to help me!